# disable JSON rendering of an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I used a scaffold to build a `number` model. I've noticed that if I go to `http://localhost:3000/numbers/3.json` it will render the `JSON` for that number. All the action in the controller says is:

```
  def show
  end
```

and the only route is:

```
resources :numbers
```

Where is rails being told that its ok to accept a `JSON` request and render the `JSON`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were `JSON` views created by the scaffolding. For example there was a file: `app/views/numbers/show.json.jbuilder` which was rendering the `JSON`

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable JSON requests at routes.rb, using constraints:

```
# Allow a HTML only
resources :numbers, constraints: {format: :html}
```

Comment: You can constrain it at namespace level too. namespace :manage, constraints: { format: :html }

Comment: @GeordeeNaliyath: I did not know that. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Cause if you don't specify format, rails will just adapt.

> cf: /numbers/:id(.:format)

Just add respond_to to your show method

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
end
```

Hope it helped